# Identify unique google home device

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Is there a way to identify unique google home device under same user account from dialogflow webhook request?

Currently i identify the user from dialogflow webhool request using the following parameter:

```
originalDetectIntentRequest>payload>user>userId
```

But under same account they are same.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are able to identify the user of the request, but not the device itself.